# Machine Learning: Why xW+b instead of Wx+b?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I started to learn Machine Learning. Now i tried to play around with tensorflow.

Often i see examples like this:

```
pred = tf.add(tf.mul(X, W), b)
```

I also saw such a line in a plain numpy implementation. Why is always `x*W+b` used instead of `W*x+b`? Is there an advantage if matrices are multiplied in this way? I see that it is possible (if `X`, `W` and `b` are transposed), but i do not see an advantage. In school in the math class we always only used `Wx+b`.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the reason:

- By default w is a vector of weights and in maths a vector is considered a column, not a row.
- X is a collection of data. And it is a matrix nxd (where n is the number of data and d the number of features) (upper case X is a matrix n x d and lower case only 1 data 1 x d matrix).

To correctly multiply both and use the correct weight in the correct feature you must use X*w+b:

- With X*w you mutliply every feature by its corresponding weight and by adding b you add the bias term on every prediction.

If you multiply w * X you multipy a (1 x d)*(n x d) and it has no sense.

Comment: If X is a collection of data records (the columns are the records and the rows are features) and W of weights (the rows are the number of input features and the columns are the output features) then it would also work. The output is a matrix (the columns are the records and the rows are the features). Of cours ethe bias has to be added, but this is no problem. I cannot se a disadvantage of this way? Thank you

Comment: In X every row is a record and every column a feature, with that notation you can use X*W. If you use a different notation (for example in X every row y a feature and every column a record) you must use W ' * X (note that W ' means the transpose of W because you need W to be a row instead a column)

Answer (score 1):

I'm also confused with this. I guess this may be a dimension matter. For a n*m-dimension matrix W and a n-dimension vector x, using x*W+b can be easily viewed as that maping a n-dimension feature to a m-dimension feature, i.e., you can easily think W as a n-dimension -> m-dimension operation, where as W*x+b (x must be m-dimension vector now) becomes a m-dimension -> n-dimension operation, which looks less comfortable in my opinion. :D

Comment: Its nice to see there are other people who are also confused with this:) Thanks for your explanation:)!

Comment: @KevinMeier I have seen many paper using _xW[:, i]_ to indicate the _i_-th component of mapped feature, so I search the web to find whether it is common to use _xW+b_ instead of _Wx+b_ in machine learning. However, I couldn't find a proper answer. Hope one can explain this quesion one day :) !